# SPI receive register size of ESP32

Tags: c++, spi, communication, esp32

ESP32 has 64 byte SPI FIFO size, but I could not find what is the largest bit size it can receive over SPI?

P.S. I need to interface a sensor, which returns 32 bit response.

EDIT to clarify why I am asking:
I am sending 32 bit request by splitting it into 4 bytes, but do not know how to recieve 32 bit response.
This function is for sending:

```
uint32_t SendRequest(uint32_t Request)
{
    uint32_t Response;
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 24);
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 16);
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 8);
    Response = SPI.transfer(Request);
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, HIGH);
    return (Response);
}
```

`SPI.transfer()` returns the respond after data send completely. Can I read the SPI register?

Datasheet of the sensor: https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/datasheet/datasheet_scc2230-e02.ashx?la=en

EDIT to update `SendRequest()` function:

```
uint32_t SendRequest(uint32_t Request)
{
    uint32_t Response = 0x00;
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, LOW);
    // Send the request in 8-bit sections
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 24);
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 16);
    SPI.transfer(Request >> 8);
    SPI.transfer(Request);
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, HIGH);
    delay(1);
    // Capture the response in 8-bit sections
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, LOW);
    Response = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);
    digitalWrite(PIN_CSB, HIGH);
    delay(1);
    return (Response);
}
```

Comment: 1 byte has 8 bits. 32 bits are 4 bytes. what is the problem?

Comment: Why I am asking, because, 32 bit data can be send by splitting it into 4 bytes. But I do not know how to capture full 32 bit  respond. I will edit my question to specify.

Comment: like 4 bytes and then <<

Comment: You don't receive the 32-bit response. You receive the 4 bytes you sent. It's then *your* job to recombine those bytes into the correct 32-bit value.

Comment: You mean receiving 1 byte after each 1 byte transfer? How slave device knows what to respond until command not send completely?

Comment: No, receiving the reply after you have sent the request. You send 4 bytes in the request - you then read 4 bytes for the response. Read the datasheet of the (unspecified) "device" - it *will* contain a protocol diagram detailing exactly what happens on each and every clock cycle of the transfer.

Comment: Exactly. But I do not know how to capture the reply after 32 bit transfer is completed. I think `SPI.Transfer` receives only 8 MSB of the response.

Comment: Are you sure you don't first start receiving the response after you have fully transferred your request? Just do four SPI.transfer(0x00) calls after the final request transmit to get the 4 bytes, then, depending on the byte order (little or big endian) of the 32 bit word, shift them back together. It's however not possible to know when your sensor sends the answer because you have provided no datasheet to us.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I was also doing it right know. But again I receive 0xFF.
`Response = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Response = (Response << 8) | SPI.transfer(0x00);`

Comment: So what are you inputting as `Request`?

Comment: I have updated the function in my question above. To capture the data I send zero. But for `Request` I am sending 32 bit SPI frames for different operations. It might have also some timing problem.

Comment: If you only ever receive all 0xFF for the response then MISO might be permanently high. Check that with a multimeter, you might have a wrong wiring